# @font-face anti-aliasing on windows and mac

Tags: css, font-face, antialiasing, font-embedding

I've used http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to create a @font-face kit.
It works fine, but the result on windows is different from the result on mac.
On windows the font seems to have a wrong anti-aliasing:
[image: Font face on Mac] this is the result on Mac with FF, Chrome or Safari (all updated to last version).
[image: Font face on Windows] this is the result on Windows with FF or Chrome.

As you can see, the result is not the same. On Windows the font is thicker and rougher.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This just looks like the normal ugly way fonts are rendered in WinXP. Some (IMO: misguided) people even prefer it.

To get anti-aliasing for desktop fonts in general on XP you have to turn it on, from Display Properties -> Appearance -> Effects -> Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts -> ClearType. The default setting “Standard” is the old-school Windows “font smudging” technique that only bothers to turn on at larger font sizes, and then often makes a mess.

IE7+ has an option—on by default—to always use ClearType anti-aliasing to render fonts in the web browser. Other web browsers will respect the user's configured font rendering method. It is a shame that so many people still have this beneficial setting turned off, but it's not really your problem.

(There is nasty hack to make Chrome perform *some* anti-aliasing on text, which is:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

but I seriously wouldn't recommend it.)

One thing you can do when the “Use the following method...” setting is set to “Standard”, to try to make the font get *some* form of anti-aliasing, is to check that the font in question doesn't have a `GASP` table telling old-fashioned TrueType renderers to disable anti-aliasing at particular font sizes. You can change the GASP table [using a font editor](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/fontinfo.html#gasp) or with the `ttfgasp.exe` command-line tool.

Comment: I've tried to enable ClearType on Windows, but the problem persist. I'm checking the GASP table as well, but: do you see other solutions? do you think that using a different font type (woff, eot, svg, etc..) can change something?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Converting the outlines to Type 1 format beziers instead of TTF splines can make a difference to the renderer used for non-ClearType font smoothing, but that's a pretty drastic step. Could you put the font up somewhere to check? Oh, another thing: does the jaggy rendering occur *everywhere* you use the font, even in a trivial test page? There are other reasons anti-aliasing can get turned off, in particular when you use an IE `filter` style (typically to reproduce `opacity`).

Comment: The font is Myriad Pro (that is a standard font on a Mac, but not on Win). If you want I can PM you the site I'm developing so that you can see it live.

Comment: OK, but bear in mind that the Mac-bundled Myriad is not licensed for web embedding. As I understand it, at the moment, the only legal way to embed Myriad is via Typekit.

Comment: I hadn't considered the legal issue. I will replace with images or use an alternative font. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: It helps me to solve anti-aliasing problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13366787/1002639

Answer (score 48):

I too have been plagued with this on Chrome and I think I've just found the answer!

Chrome didn't like the default fontsquirrel.com generated CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HLC';
    src: url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.svg#HLC') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

To fix, i moved the SVG line:

```
url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.svg#HLC') format('svg')
```

to the top of the list. Now I see anti-alias fonts! I guess Chrome wants to be first...

```
/* THIS WORKS FOR ME */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HLC';
    src: url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.svg#HLC') format('svg'),
         url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/_styles/hlc/hl-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Hope it works for you too. Enjoy!

Comment: I was using Open Sans from google web fonts and after reading this checked what fonts were included in the package. It only returns the woff file so i went to fontsquirrel, downloaded the package and applied your fix, it worked! It's weird because on googles web fonts site they suffer from the lack of anti-aliasing as well.

Comment: @tq Yeah, this used to work before; up until version 18 or 19 I think, now it renders SVG text the same way it renders normal text. :(

Comment: I haven't seen any changes in my sites on Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m. Feel free to PM me, I wouldn't mind taking a look to try and duplicate or help with the issue.

Comment: It works fine for me, version `25.0.1364.152 m` and fonts `KaushanScript` and `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in chrome in windows, with firefox not so much.

Comment: This was broken in V22/23 but has been fixed once again. Anyone using a modern version will be okay with this solution. Verified working in 29, 30, 31, and the newest 32.

Comment: Using SVG all the time isn't the best way, since SVG lacks hinting information. Without hinting the font looks more blurry than it has to on systems with font-smoothing enabled. Therefore I wrote [a small script called Font Smoothie](https://gist.github.com/letorbi/5177771), which detects if font-smoothing is enabled and corrects the CSS only if needed. I also created [a webfont generator named Fontie](http://fontie.flowyapps.com/), which takes a otf or ttf and generates a package with proper hinted webfonts, CSS and Font Smoothie for you.

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this. Applying a slight -webkit-text-stroke does the trick for me whatever the format (extension) of the font you are using. Some recommend a -webkit-text-stroke: 1px but to me it alters the font look too much (make it too strong). But a 0.5px one makes the stroke almost unnoticeable and it turns on the antialiasing:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;
```

Put it in your css definition for html tag and you're done!

Comment: Doesn't work for me here (Chrome 24 / Win XP / ClearType disabled).

Comment: What are the effects on this in OSes like OSX that render the font properly by default? Will it make it extra strong?

Comment: Works on Chrome 26.0.1410.64 Windows 7 ClearType enabled. But it's still a hack. Not the same font anymore.

Comment: I've recently had issues with setting a text stroke global when working with mobile drop down menus using jQuery as it sometimes causes a 'lag' in the slideDown/slideUp/slideToggle effects, so I'm a little cautious about using this css method now.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a font called Vegur that looks like Myriad Pro but is legal to embed in a website.
Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 there are lots of fonts that look like Myriad, or rather Frutiger, which is the font Myriad was ‘influenced’ by. “Humanist sans that looks like Frutiger” is almost a genre of its own now!

Answer (score 4):

I've done a little research, and I've found a hack that I think makes a difference. Put this in your CSS with your font variables:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
```

As well, I find that a full-on black (`#000000`) doesn't help matters either. Using a very dark seemed to help me.

Comment: For me the antialising does not apply until `rotate(-0.03deg)`. Also, in the Canvas you can do `setTransform(1, 0.001, 0, 1, 0, 0)` and it also get antialised.

Comment: Update: No longer working in Chrome 15.0.874.106 m. Though it does work in IE9 and Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Changing setting in Windows or a browser itself is not a solution. When you use `@font-face`, you want the font to look nice on every screen in every browser, not just in yours.

The trick with

```
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
```

or

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
```

doesn't work anymore in Chrome 16.0.912.63 m, Windows Vista.

I couldn't find a way to overcome this issue though.

Answer (score 2):

This is code im using to fix "Chrome rendering problem":

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontname';
    src: url('fonts/fontname.eot');
    src: url('fonts/fontname.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/fontname.svg') format('svg');
}

/*if mozilla*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'fontname';
        src: url('fonts/fontname.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
}
```

:) it works for me...FINALLY!

Answer (score 0):

> -webkit-transform: rotate(-0.0000000001deg);
>
> Update: No longer working in Chrome 15.0.874.106 m. Though it does work in IE9 and Firefox – >Zequez Nov 4 at 15:28

UPDATE: This is working (at least for me) in Chrome 15.0.874.121 m.

IE9 and Firefox shouldn't need it, or be targeted by it since the selector specifies `-webkit-`.