# why does the font appear so differently? (in web and photoshop)

Tags: css, fonts

i've actually never encounter this problem before. I usually start designing my layout in photoshop then transfer it to my page.

Somehow, lately i've been using georgia font alot, and i love it when the style is italic, but what comes out in photoshop does not reflect back in the webpage when i set it in css.

[image: Font images]

in the pic above, 1. is what i saw in photoshop and what i wanted, but 2. is what i got, no matter what i try changing, be it font-weight or font-size it remains as bold. I want it thinner, is there a way? I tried font-stretch too btw.

Comment: Font-rendering engines differ in browsers from other applications and on different platforms. As for how you can approximate what you're trying to get, experimentation is the only thing I can recommend. Decreasing the font-size is where I would start.

Comment: With Firefox 4 and below keep in mind that fonts often look bigger than other applications because they were not using the same value for a pixel as other applications and browsers, see "Consistent CSS Units" in this page => http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/technology/#css

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060607/font-face-anti-aliasing-on-windows-and-mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the bold, it is a system [font smoothing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html).

You are able to change (or disable as in your case) font smoothing in Photoshop, but you can't do it with CSS, [unless you are using CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop) and compatible browser.

Added: I wouldn't recommend you to even try to change the font smoothing. That's the user right - to have [fonts rendered the way she likes](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20020819.html).

Comment: Thanks, but in photoshop i did not use font smoothing, thanks for the links tho :) will have a look!

Comment: Yes, you can disable font smoothing completely in Photoshop: http://dansnetwork.com/smooth-fonts-in-photoshop/, but it is enabled in the operating system, so browser renders it smoothed.

Comment: thanks, but can i disable it through CSS? because i'm trying with xampp and by using font-smooth: never; it doesn't seem to work, maybe i should try online?

Comment: As far as I know, only WebKit-based browsers support this property, but you have to use vendor prefix: http://www.usabilitypost.com/2010/08/26/font-smoothing/