# Windows font rendering problems with @font-face in CSS

Tags: css, windows, font-face, typography

I'm having troubles with @font-face on Windows computers (no mather what browser). It works okay in linux and osx.

This is the css code i'm using (generated with font-squirel)

Check the screenshots for the problem.. There seem to be 2 problems

- On windows the fonts are 'dancing'. The are not aligned on the baseline.
- On windows the fonts look not anti-aliased.

Anybody has an idea? Thanks in advance.

**Screenshot in OSX & Linux:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [j3rn.org](http://j3rn.org/images/ob_font1.png))</sub>

**Screenshot in Windows:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [j3rn.org](http://j3rn.org/images/ob_font2.png))</sub>

**CSS code**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SchulbuchNordFett';
    src: url(assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-fett-webfont.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-fett-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-fett-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-fett-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-fett-webfont.svg#SchulbuchNordFett') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SchulbuchNordNormal';
    src: url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-normal-webfont.eot');
    src: url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-normal-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-normal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-normal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('assets/fonts/schulbuchnord-normal-webfont.svg#SchulbuchNordNormal') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: 1) That first screenshot isn't OS X at all, that's Linux only 2) Go back to Font Squirrel's generator, choose the Expert option, and make sure Hinting is enabled. Replace with the newly-generated font files, and see if the rendering improves.

Comment: Thanks boltclock, your right, it's a linux screenshot. I tried your suggestion straight away. But i gave no solution. I did see that 'hinting' is checked by default. I just tried it anyhow to make sure. It's also not a caching problem (i gave fonts new filenames and changed the css filepath).

Comment: [I've tried this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9087123/1428241) but i won't work on firefox and also it didn't work fully correct, problem was show utf-8 foreign charahters on chrome/safari/opera.

Comment: Windows turns off font antialiasing on a number of conditions: if the font is large, if the font is small, if it uses Postscript outlines instead of TrueType outlines, etc.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue with some of our fonts, and I'm pretty sure what fixed it was setting "Truetype Hinting" to "Keep existing".

[image]

Comment: This fixed our issue with terrible rendering of Montserrat on all Windows browsers. (The i was indistinguishable from the l in smaller type.) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue some weeks ago. We are storing vector graphics in a font file to avoid implementing seperate images or css sprites. A simple workaround would be to use for instance font squirrel

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

without(!) the optimizing option, which processes your font to optimize it for the web and sometimes breaks it due to compression attempts, if they don't fulfill some standards. A possible drawback might be, that your files become a bit larger. You can also try this webservice:

http://fontface.codeandmore.com/indexnew.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was already using these websites, and now tried your method; convert fonts without optimizing. It was useless /:

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as antialiasing goes, windows can be pretty ugly when rendering out thin text. A common trick is to try applying a text stroke like so:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.3px
```

As far as your baseline problem, that seems to be an issue with the actual font. If you're not attached to @font-face, I'm pretty partial to [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

You'd just have to include a css link in your header, then attach the corresponding font to a css class.

Comment: These aren't healthiest ways but `text-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc` will solve our problem also.

Comment: They don't work the same way. It really depends on preference and maybe even your color scheme, but in my experience, trying a `text-shadow` didn't provide me with the desired appearance that `-webkit-text-stroke` provided

Comment: Please, note `-webkit-text-stroke` is a **non-standard feature** and Mozilla recommends against using it in production: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke)

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, but I think you uploaded (illegally?) a pre-web built alternative to Helvetica into FontSquirrel.com's "roll-your-own" @face-kit... tisk tisk.

The results you're getting are pretty typical for how PCs render fonts on screen.

FF Schulbuch Nord: Created in 1991 ($239 if you want to buy it from fontshop.com).
http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/singles/fontfont/ff_schulbuch_nord_ot_regular/&s=c

TexGyre on fontsquirrel is a pretty fair (though, not as pretty) alternative to Helvetica, and it looks good on PCs, Macs, etc.