# @font-face rendering on webkit browsers

Tags: google-chrome, css, font-face

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@font-face anti-aliasing on windows and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060607/font-face-anti-aliasing-on-windows-and-mac)

This is my css:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Museo500Regular';
        src: url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.eot');
        src: local('?'), 
        url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.svg#webfontr3rD8cn7') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

.loginUser form h2{
font-family: Museo500Regular,sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

On IE,Firefox,Opera render well only on webkit browser is not rendering well, can anyone tell me why ? :|

Comment: What does "not rendering well" mean? I haven't experienced any issue with `@font-face` in Chrome, which is my primary browser. Can you set up an actual demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: HI now you put the wrong font fmaily apply this do this .loginUser form h2{font-family: 'Museo500Regular', sans-serif;
}

Comment: @lanzz  see the difference between ie,firefox,opera and chrome... http://oi46.tinypic.com/11w98cz.jpg

Comment: @Rohit Azad sory, my mistake when I have copied ... i have edited description.

Comment: Is this on Windows? Haven't seen an aliased font on Mac, ever. Might be a Windows-specific font renderer problem.

Comment: @lanzz yes is windows xp

Comment: Do you have a demo page where we can see this? It's quite difficult to find the exact problem otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

To get proper bold text, you need to use a bold (700) version of the font. If you use another weight and just ask browsers to bold it, they may algorithmically thicken the strokes, and this results in poor or awful rendering, depending on browser.

Comment: I have generated font with    fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator    and if I open test file with chrome I see even there the differences between ff and webkit :|

Answer (score 1):

Rohit: I am sure that was just a typo, as it would break in all browsers

Have you tried the following method:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Museo500Regular';
src: url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.svg#webfontr3rD8cn7') format('svg');
}
```

It has always worked for me.. 
Otherwise it might be an error in your Woff file, since that is the one webkit uses

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
font-family: 'Museo500Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ubuntu-r-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Museo500/MuseoSans_500.svg#webfontr3rD8cn7') format('svg');
```

Also try adding the following to the .htaccess

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
```

Comment: where I must add that AddType ? on css file?

Comment: I don't thinl this is a solution ...

Comment: I was just suggesting the last solution. It might help, that's all. Try generating the font-face css using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator and try again. This might help too.

Comment: yes thank you, but already tested this :|