# CSS Google Fonts Bolder on Safari

Tags: html, css, fonts, bold

I have done a lot of looking into this problem on my own and I know that this is a common problem with a lot of people, but many usually find a solution to their problem, however I cannot.

I'm currently using this font: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial

And It renders perfectly on Windows 7 Firefox, Chrome, and IE. However, on Safari, the font weight is overly bold.

See comparison below:

[image: Firefox vs Safari]

Now this example is a major problem for the h6 tag:

```
h6 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Questrial;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; //This does nothing to help
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

So is there even a fix?

Comment: It might be an order issue [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060607/font-face-anti-aliasing-on-windows-and-mac/9041280#9041280)

Comment: I don't have the font, I'm taking it directly from google: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

Comment: Agreed :-) However, it's just a regular CSS file which you can save and test with. Also, have you tried `subpixel-antialiased` instead of `antialiased`?

Comment: Ah never mind, Google always seems to return just a .woff :(

Comment: Subpixel still does not fix the problem

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5082824) is useful (although it also states that different browsers render fonts differently and there's sadly only so much you can do about it).

Comment: Yeah I've tried that already. I'm thinking I may have to end up switching to a non Google font sadly, or just forget about Safari users.