# Firefox font-face rendering looks very different to e.g. Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, text-rendering

I am having trouble with `@font-face` in CSS. The font I am using looks very different in each browser.

See this example in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

And here in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

I don't know what causes this problem. I already tried to use `text-rendering` and I also tried changing the order of the `url`-properties in the `@font-face` declaration.

I am using Windows 7 Professional and Firefox V30.

Can somebody inform me about the reason for this issue and tell me how I could fix it?

Many thanks.

//EDIT:
This is the `@font-face` declaration I am using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('myFont.eot');
    src: url('myFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('myFont.svg#myfont') format('svg'),
        url('myFont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('myFont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight : normal;
}
```

As I wrote above I already played with the order of this commands.

In my particular problem you can see [this page (footer)](http://tablet.siemens.com/entry/cc/en/) showing the problem.

Comment: show the font-face code you are using

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060607/font-face-anti-aliasing-on-windows-and-mac/9041280#9041280

Comment: Impressive, that doesn't even look like the same font size. I'd try dropping the svg version for debugging purposes: IIRC, only Chrome supports SVG fonts anyway.

Comment: Yes, it looks like both browsers use very different engines to render fonts. Unfortunately removing the svg-url did not change anything..

Comment: @dippas "As I wrote above I already played with the order of this commands."

Comment: can i know the font name ?

Comment: The font is called Siemens Sans Bold. It is in use e.g. here http://tablet.siemens.com/entry/cc/en/. The footer on this page shows the font problem.

Comment: What if you will change order of the loading in your @font-face and you will put SVG on first place (like default)?

Comment: @Wado I can only repeat: "As I wrote above I already played with the order of this commands."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a font issue since all opportunities that work for others do not affect the problem. Switching to a other font is the only solution in this moment.

Answer (score 3):

Most modern browsers use DirectWrite on Windows to render text, except for Chrome.  Luckily they are implementing it now and it was recently set as the default in the latest Chrome builds.  Thats the good news, the bad news is that it still has bugs and doesn't always render fonts correctly. You can see if this is a problem by disabling it to see if that fixes the issue.

To disable DirectWrite type `chrome://flags/` in the address bar and find the option labeled 'Disable DirectWrite'. If this does fix the issue, you should log a bug with the examples of your text rendering so that it can be fixed.

You can read more about it on the Chrome blog at http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/chrome-37-beta-directwrite-on-windows.html.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I am searching a way to fix this font issue so that it looks not so different on each browser, but website-based. So a change in the browser settings or on the graphic-card would not be a solution for me, sorry. But it is still interesting!

Comment: If you turn off DirectWrite and it fixes your font issue, then unfortunately that means there is no way to fix the issue in your website code. There is no magic 'make my font look the same in all browsers' css or html.

Comment: See my updated post. The link shows the font issue in the footer. As I wrote above I'm searching a fix for firefox. Do you know a way to fix it firefox-based?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it with the follow small thing

```
color:#505563;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #eeeeee;
```

In other words just add text shadow and it will work fine, play with the correct colors as an artist. Try this

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #eeeeee;
```

Comment: Also the fonts I use I saved them on my own hosting because if you retrieve them from Google it will not always load correctly neither faster

Comment: Maybe this has solved the problem with your font, but not with the font used on the demo page. I've tested it as you said, but that did not affect the problem. Maybe 'Dosis' is a tiny font, and the text-shadow makes the font stable in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have accessibility features that override CSS. Make sure the text or page settings are not zooming. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages

If nothing else this will at least rule out one variable, making debugging more effective.

Comment: You could test it yourself. I have no zoom enabled on the demo page, but the effect still appears.